# in Ksh, why does the last (empty) line of my multi-line string disappears when saving it in a variable?

Tags: ksh, carriage-return, multilinestring

While implementing a script, I am facing the following issue : 
when putting the multi-line result of a command into a variable, it seems the last (empty) line of my multi-line string disappear.

This line is "empty", but however, I can not lose the carriage return it contains (because I am concatenating blocks of code saved in DB and containing "\n" character into a human-readable string... If I lose some of the "\n", I will lose a part of my code indentation)

Here is the code to illustrate my issue :

```
test="A

B
";
test2=`echo "$test"`;
echo "||$test2||";
```

This returns

```
||A

B||
```

while I was expecting :

```
||A

B
||
```

--> the last (empty) line has disappeared... and a carriage return is thus missing in my human-readable code.

This issue only occurs when the last line of my multi-line string is empty...

Do you know

- Why this last line disappears ?
- How I can ensure my last empty line is saved in my multi-line string variable ?

Note that I can of course not use the easiest solution

```
test2="$test";
```

because the complete process is rather :

```
test="^A\n\nB\n^"
test2="`echo "$test" | sed -e 's/\^//g'`";
```

but I tried to simplify the issue the most I could.

Comment: Command substitutions always trim trailing newlines -- that's in accordance with design and specification. Otherwise, `foo=$(echo foo)` wouldn't contain the string `foo`, but would have a trailing newline -- that would confuse people.

Comment: BTW, which specific version of ksh is this? There are a lot of different, incompatible implementations floating around.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy None of the command I tried to find which ksh version I am using worked... I tried "ksh --version", "echo ${.sh.version}" & "echo $KSH_VERSION". If you know other possibilities to identify my ksh version I am very interested ;-)

Comment: What's the operating system? If it has a package manager, we can ask *that* what your ksh is.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : IBM AIX 7.1.0.0

Comment: Hmm. Some versions of AIX use rpm (allowing the `rpm -q` family of subcommands to be used to check installed package details), but I don't recall which those are.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think I finally found the version by doing
Escape 
CTRL+V

Result : Version M-11/16/88f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command substitutions always trim trailing newlines -- that's in accordance with design and specification. If you don't want that, you can append a fixed sigil character to your output and trim it, such that the newlines you want to preserve are *before* the sigil:

```
test="A

B
"
test_wip=$(printf '%sEND' "$test")
test2=${test_wip%END}
```

Comment: Indeed, with this idea, I can get the result I want
test_wip=$(printf '%sENDOFLINE' "$test");
test_wip2="`echo "$test_wip" | sed  -e 's/\^//g'`";
test2=${test_wip2%ENDOFLINE};

Let's just hope nobody will use "ENDOFLINE" in the code I am trying to interprete.

Comment: @Seba991 : you can shorten that a bit with `test2="$(echo "${test}"ENDOFLINE | sed -e 's/\^//g')"` ; `test2="${test2%ENDOFLINE}"`

Comment: @Seba991, well, we're only removing exactly one `ENDOFLINE` (the one at the very end), so it doesn't matter if there *is* an extra literal one in the data.

Comment: @markp, modern versions of real ksh (which, granted, it appears the OP doesn't have) optimize `var=$(printf ...)` to be equivalent in efficiency to bash's `printf -v var ...` with no subshell; using `sed` is going to be significantly more expensive.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : ummm, not sure I understand how `printf` can replace `sed` to strip out the `^`'s ... or are you saying `sed` is still required, but a bit of overhead can be eliminated by using `$(printf..)` instead of `$(echo..)`

Comment: Ahh -- missed the context (of the OP trying to perform a separate operation, and not having a PE in whatever odd ksh they have locally available).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I understand your comments about `$(printf...)` being more efficient, and thanks for the heads up; but OP has extended the issue to also needing to remove an actual caret (^), but since `${...//^}` is not an option ... `sed` to the 'rescue'; yeah, we're talking past each other :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to work around the issues that arise from assigning the output from `echo` to a variable (eg, stripping of trailing \n's), consider using `ksh`'s built in string processing in this case, eg:

```
$ test="^A\n\nB\n^"
$ test2="${test//^}"
$ echo "||${test2}||"
||A

B
||
```

- `//^` : remove all `^` characters

Comment: When I try this, I get error : 
    ksh: test2="${test//^}": 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.

Comment: hmmmm, what does `ksh --version` return?

Comment: @Seba991, that command substitution is valid in ksh 93u+; if you're using an old version (or a not-quite-compatible 3rd-party clone such as mksh), you should specify that in the question.

Comment: @markp ksh --version returns "--version: 0403-010 A specified flag is not valid for this command"

Comment: @Seba991 : yeah, probably an older (or incompatible) version of ksh